# MP4 problems after installing ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: sound, firefox, video, codecs, mp4

After installing ubuntu-restricted-extras on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, I can play MP3 but not MP4 in both Firefox 82.0.3 (64 bit) and VLC 3.0.9.2.  Ubuntu is running as a guest in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.

When I play an MP3 in FF and VLC, there is no issue.  Sounds good.

When I try to play an MP4 in VLC, the video is fine but the sound is just quick bursts every few seconds.

Firefox's behavior is even more difficult to understand.  If I try to play a local MP4, the first time I hit play it does nothing.  If I pause it and hit play again I get both video and audio.  The third time of pause/play, nothing.  The fourth time, fine.  And so on.

I've tried researching this on Google for the past two hours, but the solutions all point to installing ubuntu-restricted-extras, which I have done.  I also tried installing ffmpeg.  And much of the advice is very old pointing to packages that no longer exist in the repository.

I'm lost and any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Try increasing the buffer times in VLC.